# Setting my native resolution resultsin display too wide for the screen

Tags: display, display-resolution

After I installed NVIDIA drivers I saw that after the restart my native Resolution was there. I applied it and it seems it is far stretched to the left so I cant see my dock. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? I have no idea why this would happen cause the Res is the native one I always used.

Answer (score 0):

Check your monitor adjustment settings. Most of them have an `auto adjust` feature that you can use, but if not, you'll have to manually adjust the horizontal width and position so the image fits on the screen.

Comment: My screen does have an autoset but the image doesnt fix as it should. The autoset its only useful for me when the screen is only a couple of pixels off sometimes. If you have any other thing to help me with id be grateful. Currently looking for a in OS solution . My display is still unknown. Flatron w1941s

Comment: The problem is this is probably not an OS issue, so fixing it in the OS isn't possible. You can try rebooting the computer, making sure the video cable is correct, unplugging and replugging the monitor, etc.